# Portend vs. Presage

Tags: word-choice, word-difference

What's the difference between *portend* and *presage*?

Do they have any differences with each other?

Comment: What does the dictionary say for **portend** and **presage**? Dictionary lookup questions are off-topic on ELL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is really no difference in the meaning of the 2 words as verbs. They both mean to warn of something to come in the future, usually something unpleasant.

It's worth noting that presage can also be a noun, meaning an omen or warning. Portend is only a verb, but we have the noun portent which is derived from the same Latin root.

Comment: I've never considered this difference before, but I for one get a more negative vibe from “portend” than I do from “presage”.

Comment: It's worth noting that *portent* is the noun form of *portend*.

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung I do too but I'm not sure why. I'm also not sure it's something that's universal or even common, which is why I didn't mention it.
One of the reasons I like ELL is that it sometimes makes me think about quirks like this.

Answer (score 2):

The words are extremely similar.  Portend has perhaps a little more flavor of logical conclusion and a little less of intuitive knowledge than presage has.  For example, the loss to Michigan may portend a difficult season for Notre Dame this year.  The dream I had last night where I  was driving and arrived at a t-junction presages an important decision I will have to make soon.